# Inject location with wikitude iOS javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, ios, wikitude, wikitude-sdk

I want to provide a custom GPS position to the Wikitude SDK but I can't figure how to use `setUseInjectedLocation` and `injectLocationWithLatitude`.

Right after creating WTArchitectView and WTNavigation I do:

```
[self.architectView injectLocationWithLatitude:48.853 longitude:2.35 accuracy:1.0];
[self.architectView setUseInjectedLocation:YES];
```

I set up this callback in js:

```
AR.context.onLocationChanged = function(latitude, longitude, altitude, accuracy)
```

And I keep getting position update but not the one I passed using `injectLocationWithLatitude:longitude:accuracy`

What I am missing here ?

Comment: Have you tried to invert the order of `-injectLocationWithLatitude:longitude:accuracy` and `-setUseInjectedLocation:`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't change anything.